# wordpress plugin mmenu dont show Navigation

Tags: wordpress, plugins, mmenu

Hello i buy the mmenu for wordpress and it dont function. 
the plugin shows me the following error message:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#]

what can i do?
here my site: http://dev.kosmos-schwarzwald.de
I use wordpress 4.5 with this plugins:
Advanced Custom Fields: 4.4.6
App look-alike menus: 2.4.0
Contact Form 7: 4.4.1
Enable Media Replace: 3.0.4
EventON: 2.3.20
Login Security Solution: 0.55.0
MyMail - Email Newsletter Plugin for WordPress: 2.1.10
Reveal IDs: 1.4.6.1
WordPress Importer: 0.6.1
Yoast SEO: 3.1.2

greentings

Leonid

Comment: What did the vendor say about this error? Does it work with the new 4.5? Is that PHP or JS console error?

Answer (score 0):

Find mmenu.js in the plugin folder. Line 180 is the issue. It's conflicting with the new version of JQuery that's shipping with WP 4.5.

Change line 180 from: .filter( "[href=#]" )

to

.filter( "[href='#']" )

Needs those extra single quotes to fix the problem.

Comment: You should note that the mmenu.js file is re-created every time you hit the "save"-button in the mmenu admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be fixed in "App look-alike menus" version 2.4.1.
After downloading and installing this version, you will need to hit the "save and publish"-button in the mmenu admin panel at least once before the issue goes away.
Hope this helps.